# Is there a YouTube Contest API?

Tags: flash, youtube

i was wondering if i can submit an entry to my YouTube Contest via API

**The szenario:**

- The user interacts on my YouTube Channel
- During this interaction we record a video from this webcam
- By the end of the recording i would like to submit this video to the YouTube contest

I know how to record a video etc. But i have no idea how to submit the video to the contest (with the users YouTube account). Is there an API? OAuth process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a YouTube API but you've got to pay for it and it's no longer supported. The way this would work is that you'd have to save the video generated from the user's web cam and upload it you YouTube via direct upload method.

You'd need to use YouTube's AuthSub authorisation in order to be able to upload the video (as it uploads to the user's account, not the channel). Once the video has been uploaded you can then submit it to the contest.

The best way to make a start is to contact YouTube regarding its advertising platform. I know that there is a pretty large media spend need in order to get the contest.